# Switch Between Open Forms in a WinForms project in VB using Ctrl+Tab

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

(using visual studio 2010, VB)
I have a multiple form windows project with "MainForm" as the main window.
when I'm in design mode in visual studio and I press Ctrl+Tab it shows a window that displays the currently open objects in Visual Studio, I want to add this feature to my project and I need a place or a tutorial to start from.

I understand the concept of Show/Hide and Form.Select() methods in Winforms projects, but I just need to know how to list the currently open forms in my project inside a window and switch between them using Ctrl+Tab feature.

Any help will be much appreciated.

I just got step 1 out of the way:
I created a list box in my mainform and added two buttons:
Button one Click event is this:

```
Dim formTitles As New Collection

    Try
        For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
            If Not f.InvokeRequired Then
                ' Can access the form directly.
                formTitles.Add(f.Text)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        formTitles.Add("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

    Me.ListBox1.DataSource = formTitles
```

this code lists the names of the currently open forms in my project.
Now button 2 Click event is this

```
Dim formTitles As New Collection

    Try
        For Each f As Form In My.Application.OpenForms
            If Not f.InvokeRequired Then
                If f.Text = Me.ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString Then
                    f.Select()
                End If
                ' Can access the form directly.

            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

this one sets the focus to the form which name is selected in the list box.

Now I need the Ctrl+Tab key press to do the magic of showing a new form when pressed and hiding it when released and switching inside it when only the tab button is repressed (the Ctrl is on Hold)

Comment: Which aspect are you stuck with?

Comment: well I want to create a form that only shows when keep pressing ctrl+tab. that's 1, I want to list the names of currently open forms in it. that's 2, I want to switch a highlight or something between the listed names and when I release the ctrl button the project sets focus to the selected name (form) from the list.

Comment: Yes, I know what the requirement is. Which part of it are you stuck with. You cannot expect somebody to give you the details of all of it. What have you tried so far? At which point did you get stuck?

Comment: Thank for taking interest in my question I'm not requesting the whole operation in a tutorial my goal is to get bits of code to do certain actions (for an example showing a form only when I hold Ctrl key) and then redesign this code to match my needs in the project.

Comment: So any updates on how to open a form on key stroke keep it open until I release the key the it closes

Comment: I think thats the only problem I have left

Comment: It's actually a combination of keys isn't it. CTRL+TAB both down to show form. Then CTRL up to hide it. You can surely handle KeyDown and KeyUp events to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this:

on the main form I use keydown event with Ctrl+Tab which opens the form that shows open windows in my project in that form there are 2 events:
keypress  with tab only which chnges the selected list item
keyup event with Ctrl only which closes the form and selects the the window I want.

Thank you.